# How to get a smooth rotate when calculated based on seconds

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a second needle which is rotating based on `seconds` in `360 deg` angle .
Rotating is like tick tick tick .....
Can there be a smooth rotation in it

Here is the required code :

```js
setInterval(clockRunner, 1000);

function clockRunner() {
  let date = new Date()
  let currentSecond = date.getSeconds();
  let secondRotation = 6 * currentSecond + "deg";

  document.getElementById("secondNeedle").style.transform = "rotate(" + secondRotation + ")";
  document.getElementById("secondNeedle").style.transformOrigin = "center 91%";
 
}
```

```css
#secondNeedle {
  position: absolute;
  height: 46%;
  width: 1%;
  top: 8%;
  left: 49.5%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0);
 
}
```

```html
<div id="secondNeedle"></div>
```

Can there be rotation like in below snippet:

```css
#secondNeedle {
  position: absolute;
  height: 46%;
  width: 1%;
  top: 8%;
  left: 49.5%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0);
  animation: example 60s linear infinite;
  transform-origin: center 91%;
}

@keyframes example {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg)
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg)
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="secondNeedle"></div>
```

Know that in above snippet rotation is not calculated . But can it possible to have the same effect

**Thanks for help in advance**

Comment: @epascarello Probably doesn't matter in an animation context. It'll be accurate enough in the long run, since OP is reading the wallclock anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure.

Since you're modifying `transform` every second, the minimal fix for the ticking is to add a linear transition for `transform` values with a duration of 1s:

```
transition: 1s transform linear;
```

```js
function clockRunner() {
  let date = new Date()
  let currentSecond = date.getSeconds();
  let secondRotation = 6 * currentSecond + "deg";
  document.getElementById("secondNeedle").style.transform = "rotate(" + secondRotation + ")";
  document.getElementById("secondNeedle").style.transformOrigin = "center 91%";

}

clockRunner();
setInterval(clockRunner, 1000);
```

```css
#secondNeedle {
  position: absolute;
  height: 46%;
  width: 1%;
  top: 8%;
  left: 49.5%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0);
  transition: 1s transform linear;
}
```

```html
<div id="secondNeedle"></div>
```

As @epascarello noted, the clock doesn't quite do the right thing when it's moving from second 59 to 0.

To avoid that wraparound effect, you'll need to keep track of the full revolutions the clock has done:

```js
let revolutions = 0;
let lastAngle = 0;
function clockRunner() {
  let date = new Date()
  let currentSecond = date.getSeconds();
  let angle = 6 * currentSecond;
  if(angle < lastAngle) revolutions += 1;
  let secondRotation = (revolutions * 360 + angle) + "deg";
  lastAngle = angle;
  document.getElementById("secondNeedle").style.transform = "rotate(" + secondRotation + ")";
  document.getElementById("secondNeedle").style.transformOrigin = "center 91%";

}

clockRunner();
setInterval(clockRunner, 1000);
```

```css
#secondNeedle {
  position: absolute;
  height: 46%;
  width: 1%;
  top: 8%;
  left: 49.5%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0);
  transition: 1s transform linear;
}
```

```html
<div id="secondNeedle"></div>
```

Comment: Have you seen what happens when it gets all the way around?

Comment: @epascarello :D Wild things, I'm sure! Added an edit to fix that.

Comment: @AKX thanks a lot for help(+1) . Can you tell the use  of `revolutions ` and how does `lastAngle` is calculated(**calculated in the sense as `angle` = `lastAngle` but before that a condition of `angle` < `lastAngle` is checked** ) and used

Comment: When the seconds are e.g. 59, the angle is 354. The next second, seconds are 0 again, so the new angle is 0. Since that's less than the last angle, `revolutions` is increased, so the effective angle after a single revolution is 360, 366, 372, etc., instead of 0, 6, 12, which would cause "rewinding".